# Generating local DB for old asp.net-MVC webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I have a inherited a project that uses a webservice used for updating a database on my server, and I am in charge of updating it.

I plan to set up a second separate database for testing purposes local to my machine that the webservice can interact with.

So far, I have tried the following:

- Generate the database from EDMX file. This failed, returning a blank DDL query.
- Manually clone from the existing database in hope the webservice would just bind automatically. This failed, returning *UnintentionalCodeFirstException*.

Comment: Providing the right connection string?

Comment: Connection string seems correct. I have gone through answers and tried quite a few alternatives. This is the one I'm on now with the least number of issues.   `<connectionStrings><add name="Database" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\<my user name>\Documents\database2.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /></connectionStrings>`

Comment: This is a wrong connection string. Once you are using model first or database first approach you must use Entity connection string with referencing .ssdl, .msl and .csdl metadata files.

Comment: I would create a new project and try to build the model from the db. The `App.config` will then have the right entity framework connection string. Sort of a hack, I am sure there are better ways to do it.

Comment: If you want to know more about [Connection Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716756.aspx)

Comment: Please give the Stackoverflow community the best chance to help you by supplying examples of code and more details of the project. This will resolve the 'low quality' warning the question currently has. I have a hunch that your project uses entity frameworks due to the 'code first' wording in the exception. I hope this helps in some small way towards finding your solution.